# Using Javalang Python library to make Java code into AST

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I've used "javalang.tokenizer.tokenize() "turning two pieces of java code into tokens,and which method that in Python's javalang library can I use to make them into Abstract Syntax Trees ,and then compare the two Abstract syntax tree's edit distance to check whether the two codes are similiar?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question accordingly.

Comment: the [getting started](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang#getting-started) suggests that `javalang.parse.parse` gives back a syntax tree, I'm not sure how to define edit distance, what have you tried to find how to do that? can you give references or code that attempts to do what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't konw whether zss Python library (https://zhang-shasha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) could help calculate the tree edit distance.I haven't tried it yet.